# Calculate ratio/percentage of no. of records in one particular category to no. of records in another category (the three categories are dimensions)

Tags: tableau-api

So my data let's say looks like this.

```
ItemID  Event   No. of Occurences
15      view        500
15      addtocart   89
15      bought      6
16      view        200
16      addtocart   11
16      bought      2
17      view        450
17      addtocart   43
17      bought      5
```

So `ItemID` and `Event` columns are `dimension` and `No. of Occurences` is a `measure`.

**So far, I've been able to:**

CALCULATE PERCENTAGE OF TOTAL for each ItemID, so for `ItemID = 15`, we have `view = 84.03%`(500/500+89+6)X100, `addtocart = 14.95%`(89/500+89+6)X100

**What I want to accomplish is:**

I want to show, for each ItemID, the PERCENTAGE of `No. of Occurences` which were `bought` to `No. of Occurences` which were `view` and also

I want to show, for each ItemID, the PERCENTAGE of `No. of Occurences` which were `addtocart` to `No. of Occurences` which were `view`.

So. For `ItemID = 15`, `No. of Occurences(bought)`/`No. of Occurences(view)` = 89/500 X 100

I'm a beginner. If I could shape this in some other way then, please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use calculated fields to easily do this.
Create 3 calculated fields (Analysis>Create Calculated Fields).

Event(Bought):

`IF [Event]='Bought' then [Count of Occurences] ELSE 0 END`

Event(View):

`IF [Event]='View' then [Count of Occurences] ELSE 0 END`

Ratio(Bought/View):

`SUM([Event(Bought)])/SUM([Event(View)])`

Add you EventId in the column shelf. Here is what it looks like for me.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Could you suggest me a some links where I can get some tutorials to learn advanced stuff in Tableau?

Comment: I would recommend that you go through the free training videos on [Tableau's official site](https://www.tableau.com/learn/training)